# fetch api not working after Network change - react native android

Tags: fetch, react-native

I have one application in which user can login and see some info.

**Issue:**

user able to login and see info and logout any number of times before changing network.but once user change network(from wifi to mobile or vice versa) and try to login and fetch information. it's throwing error:**Network request failed at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (fetch.js:441)**

**Note:** i am using fetch api for network call.

**Fetch Api call:**

```
export const request = async function request(path, body = null, method = 'GET') {
  try {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': body instanceof FormData ? 'multipart/form-data' : 'application/json',
    };
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken');
    if (token) {
      headers.Authorization = token;
    }
    const config = {
      method,
      url: Config.API_URL + path,
      headers,
    };
    if (!['HEAD', 'GET'].includes(method.toUpperCase())) {
      config.body = body instanceof FormData ? body : JSON.stringify(body);
    }
    const response = await fetch(Config.API_URL + path, config);
    const data = await response.json();
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      throw data.error;
    }
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error', path, e);
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
```

**Error**

```
Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (fetch.js:441)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:567)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:397)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:503
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:179)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:351)
    at MessageQueue.js:116
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (MessageQueue.js:314)
```

**SDK Version:**

compileSdkVersion: 25

buildToolsVersion: "25.0.2"

minSdkVersion: 16

targetSdkVersion: 25

I am beginner in react native. not able to identify the problem. any help will be appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: can you show your error and fetch function ?

Comment: Are u testing your app in Android API 24 (Android 7.0)?.

Comment: @RaviRaj i am using sdk version 25.

Comment: @Deva please check updated question.

Comment: `Config.API_URL` are you using any hardcorded URL like `localhost` or local IP address of the development server?

Comment: @RaviRaj i am using url for production server.